# Humans' missing piece myth identification

Tags: myth-identification, creation

Does anyone know a myth that refers/explains the feeling of incompleteness that humans have, and which drives us, makes us seekers of a missing something/fulfillment?

Ideally an ancient or primitive myth.

I find creation myths with embedded references to the disconnection between human and god/divinity, but not a mention to to a identifiable missing part or piece.

Comment: When I was a kid, I remember hearing the story about how when the gods created man and woman and were sewing them closed, the man had a little extra string hanging off but on the woman there was a touch too little.  (Don't know if that originates from actual mythology though, but it certainly has the flavor of legit folklore and seeks to explains both sexual anatomy and possibly why the sexes are attracted to each other--when they merge in sexual union there is just the right amount of string;)

Comment: The only thing it makes me think of is the 'Androgyne myth' in Plato's *Symposium*.

Comment: @DukeZhou Is that supposed to the origin of the phrase "stringing someone along"? ;)